# inoke setter method giving exceptions

Tags: java, reflection

I tried googling in stack overflow and other sites. But, I couldn't get the answer that's why I am posting here.

I have taken one bean class "BeanEx"

```
public class BeanEx {
    private String queryCode;

    private String itemId;

    private int infoId;


    public String getQueryCode() {
        return queryCode;
    }

    public void setQueryCode(String queryCode) {
        this.queryCode = queryCode;
    }

    public String getItemId(){
        return itemId;
    }
    public void setItemId(String itemId){
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public int getInfoId() {
        return infoId;
    }

    public void setInfoId(int infoId) {
        this.infoId = infoId;
    }
}
```

my main method java file

```
BeanEx myClass = new BeanEx();
Class<?> objClass = myClass.getClass();
BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(objClass);
PropertyDescriptor[] props = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
MethodDescriptor[] methodDescriptors = info.getMethodDescriptors();
Map<String, String> beanMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (PropertyDescriptor pd : props) {
    System.out.println(pd.getName());
    System.out.println(pd.getReadMethod().getName());
    try {
        System.out.println("hihi = " + pd.getWriteMethod().getName());
        pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(objClass.newInstance(),
                new Object[] { "praee" });
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        System.out.println("ignoring exception");
    }
    // return pd.getName();
}
```

i am getting exceptions...

```
class
getClass
ignoring exception
infoId
getInfoId
hihi = setInfoId
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javaapplication1.RegularExpressionExample.getFieldName(RegularExpressionExample.java:44)
    at javaapplication1.RegularExpressionExample.main(RegularExpressionExample.java:23)
```

what could be issue..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call

```
new BeanEx().setInfoId("hello");
```

when this method takes an `int`